# Unable to get the Shibboleth IDP login page

Tags: shibboleth

I am trying to integrate a Shibboleth IDPV3.4.1 with my SP which is a server called as ClearPass. I am using the Linux platform of the Shibboleth IDP. I configured the relyingparty.xml, attribute-filter.xml, attribute-resolver.xml,ldap.properties, and also the  and uploaded the metadata to the /metadata/sp-metadata.xml also updating the metadata-providers.

I am trying to use the password authentication flow with LDAP, however the issue is that I never get the login page when I initiate the SAML transaction from my SP. I get an error saying "Web Login Service -Stale Request". I have attached the screenshot of the error
[Stale Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4izlu.png)

I attempt to do a resolver test using the

http://shib.nslab.com:8080/idp/profile/admin/resolvertest?requester=https://chandracppm.nslab.com/networkservices/saml2/sp&principal=chandu

requester   "https://chandracppm.nslab.com/networkservices/saml2/sp"
principal   "chandu"
attributes
0
name    "sAMAccountName"
values
0   "chandu"

and I get the attributes from AD in return, which shows the connection to AD is working. 
However the authentication page does not appear from the IDP when I try to access the resource in my SP, I only get the Stale request Error.

The error that I see in the logs/idp-process.log is as follows

**2018-12-10 19:26:08,222 - 10.23.20.81 - ERROR [org.opensaml.profile.action.impl.DecodeMessage:73] - Profile Action DecodeMessage: Unable to decode incoming request
org.opensaml.messaging.decoder.MessageDecodingException: Shibboleth Authentication Request message did not contain the providerId query parameter.
        at net.shibboleth.idp.saml.profile.impl.BaseIdPInitiatedSSORequestMessageDecoder.getEntityId(BaseIdPInitiatedSSORequestMessageDecoder.java:128)
2018-12-10 19:26:08,223 - 10.23.20.81 - WARN [org.opensaml.profile.action.impl.LogEvent:105] - A non-proceed event occurred while processing the request: UnableToDecode
2018-12-10 19:26:08,224 - 10.23.20.81 - DEBUG [org.opensaml.saml.common.profile.logic.DefaultLocalErrorPredicate:143] - No SAMLBindingContext or binding URI available, error must be handled locally**

I am new to setting up Shibboleth IDP, not sure what I am missing.

Any inputs would be appreciated

Comment: StaleRequest usually is related to the expiration of the SAML assertion. Make sure you clear your browser cookies when you attempt the authentication, and use a tool like SAMLTracer to download and parse the actual SAML assertion that the IDP receives.

Comment: Also... there's not enough info to be sure but "Shibboleth Authentication Request message did not contain the providerId query parameter" indicates that you're potentially trying and IdP-first flow and not providing all of the requisite query parameters in the URL.

Comment: I was able to get this working by installing a Shibbolethv3 IDP docker image thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Shibboleth fails to decode the message. This behavior is to be seen if the AuthnReq is being sent to POST endpoint instead of Redirect or vice versa or if any of both endpoints are not configured properly. On UI, the error you will notice for this is "StaleRequest". I got a similar error in idp-process.log file "org.opensaml.messaging.decoder.MessageDecodingException: This message decoder only supports the HTTP GET method". The issue is pertaining to incorrect or misconfigured endpoints.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get this working by installing an IDP docker image from here

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qb5XTde1nulCdA_8QUei48CxDj0lQs7ShD622Ze_4II/edit

The authentication flow is working now